# Ctrl-dragging IBOutlet from UIView inside ViewController

Tags: ios, interface-builder, iboutlet

I´v included a image for illustrative purposes, Looking at the picture there is a UIView with a UIImageView inside it on the left. On the right I got the Controller for the Custom UIView - but ctrl-dragging IBOutlets does not work - is there a fix?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the UIImageView a subview of your custom UIView?  Do you have that view set to be your UIView subclass?

Comment: @Simon yes the UIView´s class is set to class: MediaItemInfoUIView, and the UIImageView is inside the UIView

Comment: I am dragging it to a subclass of UIView that is set in IB, does it need to be a subclass of ViewController to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are dragging to the wrong class. You are trying to drag to a `UIView` subclass, but you probably want the `UIViewController` subclass instead.